# Populating the tableView sectioned table with single array

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I have table in which there are many sections and data to be displayed in all sections is in one array resultArray so how to display the data in sectioned normally when we have two sections then we create two array one for each sections but here are multiplee sections how to solve this issue.

Thanks

My Result Array is

```
NSArray *tempArray =[[DataController staticVersion] startParsing:@"http://www.celeritas-solutions.com/pah_brd_v1/productivo/catalogMaster.php"];

for (int i = 0; i<[tempArray count]; i++) {

    id *item = [tempArray objectAtIndex:i];
    NSDictionary *dict = (NSDictionary *) item;
    ObjectData *theObject =[[ObjectData alloc] init];
    [theObject setCategory:[dict objectForKey:@"category"]];
    [theObject setSub_Category:[dict objectForKey:@"sub_Category"]];    
    [theObject setContent_Type:[dict objectForKey:@"content_Type"]];
    [theObject setContent_Title:[dict objectForKey:@"content_Title"]];
    [theObject setPublisher:[dict objectForKey:@"publisher"]];
    [theObject setContent_Description:[dict objectForKey:@"content_Description"]];
[theObject setContent_ID:[dict objectForKey:@"content_ID"]];
[theObject setContent_Source:[dict objectForKey:@"content_Source"]];


    [resultArray addObject:theObject];
    [theObject release];
    theObject=nil;
```

}

And Number for sections in the table are in category Array

```
   - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

return [categoryArray count] ;

    }
```

Title for sections

```
      - (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
     {

      return [categoryArray objectAtIndex:section];
}
```